# Socket io user disconnected with ping timeout reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My website works with node js and socket io server side.
Everything work good but after some time my clients gets disconnected with ping   timeout reason, i try last night to add more seconds to ping timeout but its make this worst.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(https,{'logger': logger, 'pingTimeout ': 60000 * 3});
```

Is someone experience this issue and can tell me the reason ?
Thanks.

Comment: What version of socket.io are you using, and what are the clients who get disconnected? (mobile devices, or desktop browsers?) I'm chasing a similar issue

Comment: did u get any success, i m having same issue, plz check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538814/socket-io-chat-disconnecting-clients-randomly-ping-timeout-and-transport-close